# optimal way of loading google maps in website

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps v3 and want it to load faster.

My setup:

At the end of a .js file

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And at end of the HTML page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

How can I make the map appear on screen quicker?

Comment: Are you sure the delay comes from these scripts?Can you post a link to this page?

Comment: i cant as the site is no live yet.

Comment: Make the development server public. You can control it with a username/password combination if required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to include both of these scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

especially if you only using Google Maps. If you are using more than one of [these Google APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/) (or these [JavaScript libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/)), include only `http://www.google.com/jsapi`. Otherwise, if you are only using Google Maps, include only `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false`. This along will save one request.

You can't really make the maps load quicker, but one of the tricks you can do is load a static map first using Google Map's [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) so it will appear to load faster.

Another trick is to load the maps only when the user asks for it. However, without knowing what your site's requirement is, it's hard to tell. With the Google library loader, you can do

```
google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:'sensor=false', callback: function(){
  var map; // initialize your map in here
});
```

or if you are not using the library loader, you can do [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Async).

Answer (score 0):

you can add an eventlistener to a button and dynamically create and fill a new iframe with the map as a content? This way the map will not be loaded untill the button has been clicked.

```
var map = YOUR GOOGLE MAPS MINIMAP SRC;
$('#button').bind('click', function() {
    if($('#iframe').size == 0) {
        $('#iframe').load(map, function() {
            $('#button').unbind('click');
        });
    }
});
```

Of course you'll have to style the iframe and position it right, this is just an idea.